# Why would xbcd.com resolve to the localhost (127.0.0.1) on Linux (Ubuntu) and Android?

Tags: linux, dns, url, operating-systems

When

1) pinging xbcd.com I get 127.0.0.1

2) using a web browser and the URL xbcd.com leads me to the local webserver, if it exists.

I've tried this on Ubuntu 14.04, multiple networks/DNS, as well as on Android CM11 on multiple WiFi/DNS networks and T-Mobile network; each of those resolve with the localhost. Both OSX and Windows appear to complain no route to host.

How/Why is this happening? I found no documentation or material on the matter. I'm curious if this is some reserved URL and Linux (Ubuntu at least I've seen)/Android have acknowledged the URL and in the OS intentionally point back to the localhost.

Anyone have any idea? Are others seeing this or have noticed this ever?

**UPDATE, required info from comment...**

`dig xbcd.com` results:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> xbcd.com
>   ;; global options: +cmd
>   ;; Got answer:
>   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39824
>   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
>
> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
>   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
>   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>   ;xbcd.com.          IN  A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   xbcd.com.       1972    IN  A   0.0.0.0
>
> ;; Query time: 35 msec
>   ;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
>   ;; WHEN: Tue Sep 23 11:39:24 PDT 2014
>   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53

`getent hosts xbcd.com` results:

> 0.0.0.0         xbcd.com

Comment: what do you see if you lookup the name using dig?  What do you see if you use [getent](http://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-using-etc-hosts-first/371281#371281)?  Update your question with details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The owner could have pointed it to 127.0.0.1  I get 0.0.0.0 when I check it.

Comment: Really, I didn't know that was possible/allowed? Interesting.

Comment: Correct, wow: http://www.who.is/whois/xbcd.com shows that too. You learn something new everyday. Thanks

Comment: For that matter, there's nothing to stop you from returning a `NS` record with private IP space (127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.1, etc.) and tricking a recursive nameserver into passing queries along. BIND does not make any assumption about what IP spaces are bogus for authoritative lookups, and it must be specifically instructed to discard these NS records via the `server` directive.

Comment: @AndrewB thanks for the additional information on how NameServers work.

Answer (score 2):

The domain resolves to the any address `0.0.0.0`, which means the address of any interface on the host on which you are running.

Thus it is not very surprising that when you try to ping it, you get `127.0.0.1`. You would get the same if you ping `0.0.0.0` directly without going through the domain name.