# Why does “medium.com” resolve to localhost IP address of 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, dns, openvpn

*This is a part of my previous question posted [here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308564/pr-io-timeout-error-on-serveral-unrelative-sites).*

---

A few days ago, I got blocked from certain sites. At first I thought it was the Government blocked me from using it. So I faked an IP address with VPN (use VPN-Gate service + OpenVPN client) to access those sites. However, as time passes, the number of sites getting blocked increasing.

So I decided to make a small list I found out none of these sites are worth it to block since it’s all (or mostly) about tech. The list below returns `PR_IO_TIMEOUT_ERROR` error in Firefox or `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome:

- medium.com (this guy was the first)
- linux.org
- itsfoss.com (can be accessible from Chrome only, but very slow)
  etc.

Below is an output from `dig medium.com`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.6-Ubuntu <<>> medium.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 285
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;medium.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
medium.com.             3600    IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 152 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 25 22:48:57 +07 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

And here is an output from `nslookup medium.com`:

```
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   medium.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

I have made sure to double check my Apache2 virtual host. Nothing in its config that can redirect 'medium.com' to `127.0.0.1`. In modern browsers (FF or Cr), it got 'Unable to connect' while w3m (text-based browser) returns my local html page.

More info:

- It happens on my Ubuntu ARM 20.10 (Raspberry Pi 4).
- I have Apache2 installed but doesn't open gate to Internet (it's simply for development stage)
- I also have OpenVPN and recently using VPNGate.

That's all I know about networking on my PC.

P.S. I read this other question: [“Why would xbcd.com resolve to the localhost (127.0.0.1) on Linux (Ubuntu) and Android?”](https://superuser.com/questions/816816) But the original poster doesn't seem to have the problem like I do so I would like to post this again to look for answer that can fix my problem.

Update 28-Jan-2021 (as user3840170 request)

Here is the output of `resolvectl`

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no 
 
Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS         
DefaultRoute setting: yes         
       LLMNR setting: yes         
MulticastDNS setting: no          
  DNSOverTLS setting: no          
      DNSSEC setting: no          
    DNSSEC supported: no          
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.43.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.43.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

Update 28-Jan-2021 (as tripleee request)

Here is result of `dig @192.168.43.1 medium.com`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.6-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.43.1 medium.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17622
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;medium.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
medium.com.             3600    IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 52 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.43.1#53(192.168.43.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 28 13:37:54 +07 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Here is result of `dig @alina.ns.cloudflare.com. medium.com`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.6-Ubuntu <<>> @alina.ns.cloudflare.com. medium.com
; (6 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10768
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;medium.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
medium.com.             300     IN      A       104.17.225.63
medium.com.             300     IN      A       104.17.31.52

;; Query time: 476 msec
;; SERVER: 173.245.58.61#53(173.245.58.61)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 28 13:38:32 +07 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 71
```

Comment: If NSLookup shows you `127.0.0.53` that means it’s going to some localhost server. But that `.53` is odd because `127.0.0.53` is not a standard localhost address. But port 53 is the port for DNS queries. My guess is somewhere on your system, there is a typo that is creating a `127.0.0.53` DNS service. Or — for all I know — some local DNS config on your system is being “cute” and responding to DNS queries on `127.0.0.53` for some app-specific config reason. In general, some local DNS config seems to be mucked up. Also check in this directory and see if anything is there: `/etc/resolver/`.

Comment: PS: In your [Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1308564/51813) you state: “…So I fake IP with VPN (use VPN-Gate service + OpenVPN client)…” My guess is your odd VPN setup is causing DNS resolution to go to `127.0.0.53`. You need to unwind that. I have gone ahead and added those VPN details to this question here since that — to me — is clearly the source of your issues.

Comment: a couple notes; the address is not resolving as 127.0.0.53, its being resolved by 127.0.0.53 (which is not doing an effective job of it). see this thread for some details about local resolver services like `systemd-resolved`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612416/why-does-etc-resolv-conf-point-at-127-0-0-53

Comment: It doesn’t resolve to `127.0.0.53`. It’s just the address under which `systemd-resolved` listens for DNS queries. Post the output of `resolvectl`.

Comment: @FrankThomas But I’m on the right track right?

Comment: @Giacomo1968, yes i think so. I'd probably want to nail down the service that's responding, and find out why its wrong. `netstat -ntlup` is helpful for finding the process that is listening on a port or address. it may  be built into the VPN client to prevent DNS leakage, or it could be there for other reasons, but clearly its not working right ;-)

Comment: @FrankThomas Seems like this might be the issue that is — ironically — on Ask Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/q/1032476/51813

Comment: @Giacomo1968 : 127.0.0.53 and all of 127.x.x.x is reserved by IANA for loopback.  Often the DNS name of localhost points to a loopback interface, most often 127.0.0.1.  Support can vary; Win9x supported only 127.0.0.1 for this, and Cisco devices may support loopback on a custom IP but not on any IP by default.  I think WinXP supported any 127.x.x.x device, though (and probably newer Windows versions as well).  IETF https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1700#page-5 and BCP 153 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735#page-4

Comment: All this speculation around 127.0.0.53 is misdirected. Having a DNS server on 127.0.0.53 simply means you are using `mdns`; it runs a local DNS server which looks for devices on your local network as part of resolving names, before going out into the public DNS to look for any resource name it can't resolve locally. The concept is called zeroconfig. [The link from a previous comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612416/why-does-etc-resolv-conf-point-at-127-0-0-53) has more information.

Comment: What does `dig 192.168.43.1 medium.com.` return? What about `dig alina.ns.cloudlfare.com. medium.com.` (or `dig 108.162.192.61 medium.com.` if you can't resolve Alina locally)?

Comment: @tripleee For the IPs, it returns as its own. But for ... cloudflare? it returns `99.83.191.119`. But are you sure it is **cloudlfare** but not **cloudflare**? Because for the **cloudflare**, I got 3 IPs in return `108.162.192.61`, `173.245.58.61`, `172.64.32.61`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, typo. From here, I see two name servers for medium.com. and they are alina.ns.cloudflare.com. and kip.ns.cloudflare.com. The syntax `dig @ns label` connects to `ns` as the name server and asks it to resolve `label`, but I forgot to put the `@`  in. Could you please [edit] to provide results for that?

Comment: @tripleee It seems the result changed a bit. For the first `dig @192.168.43.1`, nothing special returned. For the next 2 digs, seems like medium has been blinded to 2 new IPs.

Comment: So your local DNS server on 127.0.0.53 is doing its job, and the 127.0.0.1 result is coming from 192.168.43.1. If this is your ISP, I guess that means they are blocking you. (Since you were able to resolve Alina, the query with the IP address for Alina is redundant - I'll edit that out.)

Comment: I once had a home router with a "security" feature which blocked more and more sites as time went by, probably by way of some built-in machine learning logic which tried to discern legitimate traffic from illegitimate malware / IoT hacks etc, and clearly getting it wrong some of the time. It had a web UI where I started whitelisting the sites I found blocked, until I simply got rid of this "helpful" hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your assist. In the `medium.com` case, it seems correct to what you assumed (I tested on phone in the same network and it got blocked as well). But I have other site, `linuxize.com`, and it doesn't seem like that. But since it is a bit different, I will make a new question instead.

For this question, I think all I could call it a day with conclusion that IPS blocked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever runs the DNS server on 192.168.43.1
configured it that way.

By manually bypassing your local mDNS server on 127.0.0.53 you can verify that the result you see in fact comes from the DNS server you have set up your system to use.  The query `dig @192.168.43.1 medium.com.` demonstrates this.

If you don't trust your current DNS server, perhaps try to configure your system to use a different DNS server. There are a few well-known public ones like 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1.